# Searching for double value in a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
IDEstudante  IDCadeira IDProfessor  Notas
100100       10100     100          12
100001       10100     103          11
100001       10103     100          14
100100       10103     103          10
100102       20100     201          15
```

I want to search for the IDProfessor that has both the value 10100 and 10103 on IDCadeira. I've tried several solution, but the results always comes back empty. It seems easy and it's driving me crazy.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know the IDProfessors  with at least two rows, combine `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`:

```
select IDProfessor  
from tablename
group by IDProfessor
having count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: tahnk you for editing my question, i was trying to edit it but you were faster and thank you very much for the awnser

Answer (score 0):

Select the records you are interested in (`where idcadeira in (10100, 10103)`), aggregate per professor (`group by idprofessor`) and count whether you got all idcadeiras (two in your case):

```
select idprofessor
from mytable
where idcadeira in (10100, 10103)
group by idprofessor
having count(distinct idcadeira) = 2;
```

Comment: @radcp Um, the whole thing was the solution

Comment: yes but the rest i had already tried i was just not using the count